# Android: Application Pause & Resume events to run system checks

Tags: android

I need to run some system capability checks such as front camera available, GPS enabled/disabled etc before allowing the user to proceed with the application.
I would like to do this each time the app is brought to the foreground, in case the user has changed the settings while the app was in the background, hence I do not want to do it just in my home screen activity.

Is there any way to achieve this in one place without having to do this in all the activities, something like an "Application level onPause / onResume" ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're supporting from API Level 14 on-wards then the following interfaces which help you to do:
Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks
ComponentCallbacks2

You should implement in application class and should define your own logic to identify.

Some Examples:

[Example 1](http://www.vardhan-justlikethat.blogspot.com/2014/02/android-solution-to-detect-when-android.html)

[Example 2](http://steveliles.github.io/is_my_android_app_currently_foreground_or_background.html)

Comment: Thanks for the posts, they are interesting. However, both approaches require me to do something in each of my activities, which I don't want to do because it is easy to forget to do it when someone on my team adds a new activity. I'm looking for a "centralized" solution. The ActivityLifcycleCallbacks has grey areas when the user transitions from one activity to another. I believe iOS has an option to receive location updates only when the app is in use. I was hoping there's something similar in Android.